# Any other solution for context resolution this in promises except bind

Tags: javascript, static, promise, this

Any lateral solution in this case when I need to know which class I'm in without using bind.

```
function Customer() {}
Customer.prototype.say = function() {
    console.log("I'm " + this.constructor.TYPE);
};
Customer.TYPE = 'customer';

function Product() {}
Product.prototype.say = function() {
    console.log("I'm " + this.constructor.TYPE);
};
Product.TYPE = 'product';

var customer = new Customer();
var product = new Product();

//cleaner interface
Promise.resolve()
    .then(customer.say) //I'm undefined
    .then(product.say) //I'm undefined


//works but looking for a solution using cleaner interface like above
//any lateral thinking
Promise.resolve()
    .then(customer.say.bind(customer)) //I'm customer
    .then(product.say.bind(product))  //I'm product
```

I'm looking for non-bind based solution, any lateral thinking based ideas?

It's an SDK I'm developing so want to give a cleaner interface and use to clients.

Comment: You have to either use `bind` a or an anonymous function, not sure what else you expect...

Comment: any way possible to get to know the type of the caller while keeping the cleaner syntax?

Comment: *"called in global scope"* No, it's called with `this` referring to the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode), which has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: Use functions instead of methods and pass objects explicitly, then you'll get rid of `bind` and `this`

Comment: @LUH3417 sorry didn't get you, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have three options:

1. `bind`, which you've said you don't want.
2. A wrapper function like this:

   ```
   .then(function(r) { return customer.say(r); })
   ```

   ...which can look like this in ES2015:

   ```
   .then(r => customer.say(r))
   ```
3. Change your objects so that they no longer use functions inherited from the prototype, but instead are instance-specific functions that close over the instance:

   In ES5 and earlier:

   ```
   var Customer = function() {
       var me = this;
       me.say = function() {
           console.log("I'm " + me.constructor.TYPE);
       };
   };
   ```

   In ES2015+

   ```
   var Customer = function() {
       this.say = () = {
           console.log("I'm " + this.constructor.TYPE);
       };
   };
   ```

   You end up creating more function objects that way, but the code within the functions will get reused by the JavaScript engine.

There's a [proposal to the TC39 committee that defines JavaScript](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) for an operator that does what you want (basically `bind` but with cleaner syntax), but it's only at Stage 0 and so is unlikely to be in ES2017.

Comment: when you say, You end up creating more function objects that way, meaning each object get's it's own copy of `say`?

Comment: @user2727195: Each `Customer` object gets its own `say` function object. On any modern JavaScript engine, that function object will share the underyling code with the `say` function objects other `Customer` instances have, but yes, it's per-instance. Which is only an issue if there will be hundreds of thousands of `Customer` objects simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1) Don't use prototypes/classes. They will create that kind of problems over and over again. Instead, use the module pattern. Since the "methods" are created inside the closure everytime, they are effectively bound:

```
function Customer() {
    function say() {}

    return {
        type: 'product',
        say
    }
}
```

2) Provide a construct to build a prototype based hierarchy of objects where all the methods are pre-bound. Note that this remove the only advantage of prototypes: Slightly less memory consumption.

3) Be adventurous and use the :: notation made available by babel: 
    then(::customer.say)
Not all that much better admittedly, and that proposition is a bit stale at the moment so it might not even enter the language officially.

Comment: your answer kinda helped me post my answer :)

Comment: I think because your return statement is incomplete, will have errors.

Comment: I'm new to this module pattern, have been using prototype based all this time, can we do inheritance with module based pattern?

Comment: "inheritance" when using the module pattern would simply consist in copying all the functions of another object inside. That said, may I suggest looking up the sentence "composition over inheritance" on google ? :D best advice ever.